# TestNG Retry failing using DataProvider if i include ITestContext context in Test Method

Tags: java, testng

Hello: is there another way to get the ITestContext in a test method? Or what am i doing wrong?

I included **ITestContext** as a parameter in the TestMethod but **Retry fails**.

In the example below if i include ITestContext in the parameter then during the retry method Test1() is not called the second time. **BUT** if i remove ITestContext from the method parameter then method Test1() is called the second time and result is as expected.

```
public class RetryProvider {
    @Test (dataProvider = "datasource")
    public void Test1(int code, String type, ITestContext context){
        System.out.println("Test1(): " + code + " : " + type);
        Assert.fail(); //** enforce a retry **/
    }

    @DataProvider(name = "datasource")
    public Object[][] getData(){
        Object[][] data = new Object[1][2];
        data[0][0] = 1;
        data[0][1] = "apple";
        return data;
    }       
}
```

**Result:** if i **exclude** parameter "ITestContext context" in the test method

```
Test1(): 1 : apple
This is from IRetryAnalyzer ::: Retrying test Test1 with status FAILURE for the 1 time(s).
Test1(): 1 : apple  [this is what is desired after retry]
```

**Result:** if i **include** parameter "ITestContext context" in the test method

```
Test1(): 1 : apple
This is from IRetryAnalyzer ::: Retrying test Test1 with status FAILURE for the 1 time(s).
::: note here that test method was not called the second time [WHY????]
```

**The Retry Code:**

```
public class RetryListener implements IAnnotationTransformer {
    @Override
    public void transform(ITestAnnotation annotation, Class testClass, Constructor testConstructor, Method testMethod) {
        IRetryAnalyzer retry = annotation.getRetryAnalyzer();
        if (retry == null) {
            annotation.setRetryAnalyzer(RetryAnalyzer.class);
        }
    }
}

public class RetryAnalyzer implements IRetryAnalyzer{
    private int retryCount = 0;
    private int maxRetryCount = 1;

    @Override
    public boolean retry(ITestResult result) {
        if (retryCount < maxRetryCount) {
            System.out.println("Retrying test " + result.getName() + " with status "
                    + getResultStatusName(result.getStatus()) + " for the " + (retryCount + 1) + " time(s).");
            retryCount++;
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    public String getResultStatusName(int status) {
        String resultName = null;
        if (status == 1) resultName = "SUCCESS";
        if (status == 2) resultName = "FAILURE";
        if (status == 3) resultName = "SKIP";
        return resultName;
    }
}
```

The xml:

```
...<suite name="NGBug Suite">
    <listeners><listener class-name="com.NGtest.RetryListener" /></listeners>
    <test name="NGBug Test"><classes><class name="com.NGtest.RetryProvider" /></classes>
    </test>
</suite>
```

Comment: Show us how you retry the failed method (do not see code for this here).

Comment: Thanks @GrzegorzGórkiewicz , i have added the retry piece into the original question.

Comment: I know it is already quite detailed, but I think what is missing is: why you need `ITestContext`? What's so useful there? Maybe it can be taken from another place. Another thing is how do you run it? If you use a `testng.xml` file, please show us.

Comment: @GrzegorzGórkiewicz, i need ITestContext to set some attributes for the current test context which will be referred later in..such as in report.

Comment: And how do you run it?

Comment: @GrzegorzGórkiewicz, updated the original question with the xml

Comment: Thanks. Will have a look at it later today.

Comment: @GrzegorzGórkiewicz, Thanks for your time.

Comment: Would it be possible for you to include all details from `context` in the `@DataProvider` annotated method?
For me it fails with "java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: wrong number of arguments".

Comment: @GrzegorzGórkiewicz, there are some case data dependent attributes that i can set only at the `@Test` method. Suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot inject an `ITestContext` into a `@Test` method when you couple a data provider (Atleast not currently and to the best of my knowledge).

So that being said, you have two options

- You skip `ITestContext` reference as a parameter in your `@Test` method and instead access it via `Reporter.getCurrentTestResult().getTestContext()` from within your `@Test` method (or)
- You inject it explicitly from within your `@DataProvider` method (see below for a sample)

**Sample code**

```
import org.testng.Assert;
import org.testng.ITestContext;
import org.testng.annotations.DataProvider;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

public class RetryProvider {
    @Test(dataProvider = "datasource", retryAnalyzer = RetryAnalyzer.class)
    public void Test1(int code, String type, ITestContext context) {
        System.out.println("Test1(): " + code + " : " + type);
        Assert.fail(); //** enforce a retry **/
    }

    @DataProvider(name = "datasource")
    public Object[][] getData(ITestContext ctx) {
        Object[][] data = new Object[1][3];
        data[0][0] = 1;
        data[0][1] = "apple";
        data[0][2] = ctx;
        return data;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your time. You have been very helpful. Option#2 `Reporter.getCurrentTestResult().getTestContext()` looks good for my task. Option#1 is also good, but hesitant to tinker with my data provider.